# Full Hard refresh of page - Ctrl+shift+r

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I would like to know how to implement a "ctrl+shift+r" command into my HTML page. I can use javascript or html.

It should be run only when people click in a link

I tried these points

```
location.reload(true);
window.location.reload(true);
```

but this steps not workings

Any idea how to implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, Do you need to delete the cache??

Comment: yes if i use this command its working fine but i want to use this in javascript any idea ?

Comment: Yes, I have some code to delete the cache of the webpage so that it will reload the whole thing without previous datas.

Comment: Show me the code in comment i want to apply

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways of doing that.
One of the ways that worked for me was adding these meta tags

`<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>`

`<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>`

`<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>`

You can also do that using that function:

```
function deleteItems() {
  localStorage.clear();
}
```

this will delete the local storage of the web page

Another way of doing that is by using this function:

```
caches.delete(cacheName).then(function(boolean) {
  // your cache is now deleted
});
```

If that doesn't work let me know in the comments, I have plenty of ways of doing that.

Comment: @Developer try the other function I just added

Comment: i tryed but why i use this i am storing my data in localstorage but i tried its not working

Comment: can you explain what is cacheName ?

Comment: It is the name of the cache you want to delete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195992/discussion-between-synapsis-and-developer).

Comment: Plus 1 - for the unrewarded effort

Comment: please post the solution you found